# select multiple xml files using file dialog and saving them

Tags: c#, xml

HI I have several xml files , I select them using open file dialog, then  delete duplicate data from those files and now I wanted every individual  files to saved as.bak file  I can select multiple files and delete those data from files but dont no how to save those files after deleting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
 using System.IO.Path;

namespace XML_Deletes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

  //single indivual file
            var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\21.xml");
            doc.Root.Elements("Incident")
         .GroupBy(s => (string)s.Element("Comment"))
         .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
         .Remove();
//doc.Save(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\22.xml");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.Filter = "XML files(.xml)|*.xml|all Files(*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

            if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                {
    if (!String.Equals(Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName),
                       ".xml",
                       StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Invalid file type selected; display an error.
        MessageBox.Show("The type of the selected file is not supported by this application. You must select an XML file.",
                        "Invalid File Type",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    }
    else
    {
    }
}  }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [XDocument.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
doc.Save(@"C:\\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\21.xml");
```

That's already in your code (though its commented out?). Are you having issues saving?

Comment: i want to save the updated files with samenamebak.xml  i dont know how to do that. the above stamtent saves single file.

Comment: how to use savefile dialog  after the  `var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\21.xml");
            doc.Root.Elements("Incident")
         .GroupBy(s => (string)s.Element("Comment"))
         .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
         .Remove();`

Comment: how to save a xml file using save file daialog.